# Why does search (ctrl-F) in Excel not work?

Tags: microsoft-excel, search

Searching for a string in Excel (via ctrl-F) comes up with "We could't find what your looking for".  The below screenshot tells the whole story.

### Why is this?

[image]

Comment: What is the format Preview*?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald I don't know - I was playing around with the "Format" drop-down menu to see if any pre-defined format would narrow the search.  No dice.

Comment: I can't count how many times I got this problem, probably some non-visible character is still there

Comment: I believe there *is* a funky character in there; problem is I'm at work on a Windows workstation and I can't just copy-and-paste the cell's contents into a shell and `od -c` it.  Sigh... (Yes, I'm a hardcore Linux hacker at home. And proud of it!)

Comment: And besides, I'm typing regular ASCII text in the search field, so even knowing what the "funky character(s)" is/are wouldn't help me. (again) Sigh...

Comment: What's the file format for this file? Try to copy the cell to anothe Workbook and paste as value, check the result.

Comment: Are you certain you cannot type those characters into the search string?  On my Windows 10 computer, I can type a `NBSP` by holding down `alt` and tying `0160` on the numeric keypad.  Or I can run `charmap` and copy/paste from there.

Answer (score 1):

The "funky character" theory is confirmed.

The text I was searching for had a plain space in it, but the contents of the cell I circled in red (in the image) has octal characters `\302 \240` which, according to Unix Stack Exchange is a "[non-breaking space](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/272163/151885)".

So, it looks like I'm screwed with plain text searches on this daily spreadsheet which usually contains 350 or so rows.  Sigh... (for the third time)

Comment: Did you try replacing the space in the Ctrl+F field with an asterisk (*)? It should show you the results regardless of the character in between those words.

Answer (score 0):

Just click the dropdown beside the format button in the FIND tool and click the "Clear Find Format" and everything will be alright again.

[image: FIND]]

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, it might be because of values from VLOOKUP. Just copy paste the values you are searching for as 'paste only values' and try. It worked for me.